# First basic playbook on Ansible is there a better way?

Tags: ansible, formatting, sysctl

Just getting my head around Ansible. Just trying to see what I am doing wrong or what is a better way to reach my goal.

Task :

My goal here is to update a file `/proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory`. I want to put the value `0` into it. I also want the value it was before I changed it to be logged and displayed to me in output in case I need to rollback.

The below works fine but wanted to see if there are better ways to do it.

```yaml
---
- hosts: "{{ target }}"
  gather_facts: yes
  become: yes

  tasks:

  - name: "update overcommit value on {{ target }} ..."
    shell: |
      echo "the value was "
      cat /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
      echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
      echo "the value now is  "
      cat /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
    register: rc
    become: true
    become_user: root

  - debug:
      var: rc.stdout_lines
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try lineinfile with integer regexp, this may be an alternative to this shell invocations or sysctl module

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your example it is recommend to use an Ansible module, [`sysctl`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/sysctl_module.html).

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: true
  gather_facts: true

  vars:

    OVERCOMMIT_MEMORY: 0

  tasks:

  - name: 
    sysctl:
      name: vm.overcommit_memory
      value: "{{ OVERCOMMIT_MEMORY }}"
      state: present
```

Since Ansible is a [Configuration Management](https://www.ansible.com/use-cases/configuration-management) it makes sure that the above task is [idempotent](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/glossary.html#term-Idempotency) and the value is available and set after. An "reporting" could than just be like

```yaml
- name: Show value
  debug:
    msg: "'vm.overcommit_memory' values is {{ OVERCOMMIT_MEMORY }}"
```

Because of

> *[Ansible lets you define when a particular task has “changed” a remote node using the `changed_when` conditional. This lets you determine, based on return codes or output, whether a change should be reported in Ansible statistics and whether a handler should be triggered or not.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-changed)*

you will get already the information if the key was there and the value not `0` if.

> *I also want the value it was before I changed it to be logged and displayed to me in output in case I need to rollback.*

For a simple reporting of the current value set you could use a reporting task like

```yaml
- name: Gather Facts OVERCOMMIT_MEMORY
  shell: "cat /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory"
  register: overcommit_memory
  changed_when: false
  failed_when: overcommit_memory.rc != 0 and overcommit_memory.rc != 1

- name: Show vaule
  debug:
    msg: "'vm.overcommit_memory' values was {{ overcommit_memory.stdout }}"
```

You may need to adjust [Defining failure](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#defining-failure) to catch cases if the key and therefore the file does not exists or if access rights are missing.

**Further Documentation**

- [Configuring System Memory Capacity](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/performance_tuning_guide/sect-red_hat_enterprise_linux-performance_tuning_guide-configuration_tools-configuring_system_memory_capacity)

Since it might be that Ansible facts are already contain the value

- [Gathers facts about remote hosts](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/setup_module.html)
- [Discovering variables: facts and magic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html)